# Representing five categories of data in one symbol using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, cartography, visualisation, rule-based

I have been given the big task of representing a lot of data in one symbol. The plan is to represent 5 categories of data in one symbol.

I hope to do this by changing factors such as:

- Fill colour
- Border colour
- Shape
- Orientation
- Size

I planned on having:

- Severity - changing *border colour*:
  - Serious - red 
  - Slight - yellow
- Road surface conditions - *changing shape*:
  - Dry - triangle
  -  Wet -
  square
- Light conditions - *changing size*:
  - Dark - small (4 points for example)
  - Light - large (8 points maybe)
- Weather conditions - *changing orientation*:
  - Fine - vertical
  -  Raining -
  45 degrees clockwise
- Casualty mode of transport - changing *fill colour*:
  - Pedal cycle -
  purple
  -  Pedestrian - green
  -  Moped - cyan
  -  Car - black
  -  Bus - white

Is there any way of doing this without typing out 80 separate statements and changing each variable individually?

Comment: expressions are your friend

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using "Data defined override > Edit...", use the following expressions. (Edit field names)

[image]

For "Size":

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "Light"='Dark' THEN 4
  WHEN "Light"='Light' THEN 8
END
```

For "Fill color":

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "Casualty mode"='Pedal cycle' THEN 'purple'
  WHEN "Casualty mode"='Pedestrian' THEN 'green'
  WHEN "Casualty mode"='Moped' THEN 'cyan'
  WHEN "Casualty mode"='Car' THEN 'black'
  WHEN "Casualty mode"='Bus' THEN 'white'
END
```

For "Stroke color":

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "Severity"='Serious' THEN 'red'
  WHEN "Severity"='Slight' THEN 'yellow'
END
```

For "Rotation":

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "Weather"='Fine' THEN 0
  WHEN "Weather"='Raining' THEN 45
END
```

For "Shape":

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "Road surface"='Dry' THEN 'triangle'
  WHEN "Road surface"='Wet' THEN 'square'
END
```

Toy data and result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I would never have got here on my own. 
The only problem I'm having is that I cannot seem to work out how to write the expression to change the shape. It doesn't have the same menu as the other features. 
Is there a trick to it?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. What is the geometry type of the layer? polygon, line or point? The answer is for a point layer.

Comment: And please remember that you need to change field names in expressions. I made it up for testing.

Answer (score 3):

All of your visual variables can be driven by expressions so you need to write 5 expressions with a number of cases for each variable.

For Example

```
case 
when  "conditions"  =  'wet' then 'square'
when  "conditions"  =  'dry' then 'triangle'
end
```

[image]